# Asp.Net, PHP, JSP What other popular languages for HTML pages generation are there?

Tags: php, asp.net, jsp, programming-languages

Asp.net, php, jsp What other popular (used alot in production) languages for HTML pages generation are there?

Comment: Define "popular" and "used a lot" . Otherwise this will probably become a list of every language in existence. Lisp, C(++), bash, perl, lua ...you name it ;-)

Comment: This should probably be community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby and Python are up there. One notable user of Python is Google.

Comment: Google uses Java extensively as well.

Answer (score 2):

In those Wiki articles you can find a lot of information of the programming languages used in (MVC) webapps:

- [Implementations of MVC as web-based frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Implementations_of_MVC_as_web-based_frameworks)
- [Comparison of web application frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks)

To sum up, the languages used are:

- ABAP Objects
- Actionscript
- ASP
- C++
- ColdFusion
- Flex
- Groovy
- Java
- JavaScript
- Informix 4GL
- Lua
- .NET
- Perl
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby
- Smalltalk
- XML
- XQuery

And a little few more. JSP as being a Java based view technology obviously falls in the "Java" category.

Answer (score 2):

JSP and ASP.NET aren't languages as such, they're frameworks on top of a language: Java in JSP's case, [your choice of .NET-based language] in ASP.NET's.

It's only really PHP that binds the programming language to the templating syntax. Elsewhere you tend to have free choice of templating system. Whilst JSP is certainly the usual choice for Java and Rails the most popular choice for Ruby, you can always choose alternatives. Meanwhile Python is a popular web scripting language with no usual ‘default’ templating system for it. You can pick whichever you like from a cast of dozens!

Answer (score 1):

Python, Perl, Ruby.